# How to get single value from array in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Tell a beginner web delepoer how to get all title from all objects in array

this is my array

```
0: {id: 6, category_id: 2, title: "Test", brand: "Test", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}

1: {id: 7, category_id: 3, title: "Test2", brand: "Test2", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}

2: {id: 8, category_id: 5, title: "New", brand: "New", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}

3: {id: 9, category_id: 1, title: "New2", brand: "New2", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}
```

Im try to use this code

```
categories: {
            handler(categories) {
                console.log('categories: ', categories[title]); //Debug
            },
            deep: true
        }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array with just the titles you can use `Array.map` and pick the parts your interested in:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 6,
    category_id: 2,
    title: "Test",
    brand: "Test",
    serial_number: "2165412315864"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    category_id: 3,
    title: "Test2",
    brand: "Test2",
    serial_number: "2165412315864"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    category_id: 5,
    title: "New",
    brand: "New",
    serial_number: "2165412315864"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    category_id: 1,
    title: "New2",
    brand: "New2",
    serial_number: "2165412315864"
  }
];

const titles = arr.map(({ title }) => title);

console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `categories` variable is actually an array here, so you can not use

```
categories['title']
// Or,
categories.title
```

here. To get all `title` property for each category inside the `categories` array you can use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method like:

```
categories: {
  handler(categories) {
    const arr = categories.map(c => c.title)
    console.log('titles: ', arr); //Debug
  },
  deep: true
}
```